# Fetch from NPM registry always fails

Tags: windows, networking, node.js

On my Windows server 2012 machine I am unable to install/update npm packages. It was working allright, but stopped one day. I tried everything and I am seriously thinking about reinstalling the system. It even works from other machines connected to same router, but it is failing on the server machine.

https://gist.github.com/capaj/58c884b4e43b966a1ed4 
shows debug logs from NPM and also **tracert** outputs. Interesting thing is, that **ping** to registry.npmjs.org works allright, but **tracert** fails with Request timed out. I have banged my head against the wall quite enough. If anyone could have at least a shot suggestion, I would be very, very glad to hear it.